# Django: Joining classes in the admin interface

Tags: django

I have, among others, a Person class and a Contract class. In the admin interface I'd like to show the contracts related to each person when I go to the Person page and not only the data I have in the class Person.

So, first, can I show in Person the data I have in Contract?

Second, how I can show the contracts related to that person and not all of them? I mean, I don't want to show all the contracts in each person only the ones related to that particular person.

Thanks.

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32, verbose_name=_(u"Name"))
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=32, verbose_name=_(u"Surname"))
    address = models.CharField(max_length=32, verbose_name=_(u"Address"))

class Contract(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person) #person hired
    contract = models.OneToOneField('self', blank = True, null = True) #allows to extend a contract
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, blank = True, null = True) #related project
```

Comment: You can modify the admin behavior of Django, introduce additional fields and also query additional foreign data.
Your question is fully covered by the official documentation, more specifically the list view:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display
If you are reffering to modifying the relations on the change / add form, then you are looking for Inline Models:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects

Comment: Did you read the tutorial? It explicitly shows you how to do this in the admin (using the examples of poll questions and answers).

Comment: Since this is my first Django project I'm sorry if the doubts are too easy. I've tried two approachs: In admin: add in the list_display of Person `contract__attribute` and like this seems doesn't work. In Model: I've inserted a method in Person calling to the Contract attributes. But I'm stuck here bcause I dont find the poll example :(

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/intro/tutorial02/#adding-related-objects, scroll to the part about inlines.

Comment: Thank you very much to all of you. It turns out to be pretty simple but at the beginning I dind't know how to start and I needed a clue.  

`class ContractInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Contract
    extra = 1

@admin.register(Person)
class Person(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_filter = ["........"]
    list_display = ["........"]

    inlines = [
        ContractInline,
    ]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class ContractInline(admin.TabularInline): 
    model = Contract 
    extra = 1 

@admin.register(Person) 
class Person(admin.ModelAdmin): 
    list_filter = ["........"] 
    list_display = ["........"] 
    inlines = [ ContractInline, ]
```